# Check if it is root domain in string

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#,

lets say I have a string

```
string testurl = "http://www.mytestsite.com/hello";


if (test url == root domain) {

// do something
}
```

I want to check if that string "testurl" is the root domain i.e http://www.mytestsite.com or http://mytestsite.com etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably meant to use a double-equals == for comparison. In C-based languages the single-equals = operator is for assignment statements, not comparisons. It would be `if (testurl == rootdomain)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Uri` class:

```
var testUrl = new Uri("http://www.mytestsite.com/hello");


if (testUrl.AbsolutePath== "/")
{
    Console.WriteLine("At root");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not at root");
}
```

Which nicely deals with any normalization issues that may be required (e.g. treating `http://www.mytestsite.com` and `http://www.mytestsite.com/` the same)

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
string testurl = "http://www.mytestsite.com/hello"

if ( GetDomain.GetDomainFromUrl(testurl) == rootdomain) {

// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string testurl = "http://www.mytestsite.com/hello";

string prefix = testurl.Split(new String[] { "//" })[0] + "//";
string url = testurl.Replace(prefix, "");
string root =  prefix + url.Split("/")[0];

if (testurl == root) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [URI.HostName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) property

The following example writes the host name (www.contoso.com) of the server to the console.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com:8080/");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "shownew.htm?date=today");

Console.WriteLine(myUri.Host);
```

If the hostname returned is equal to "http://mytestsite.com" you are done.